# Synonym for un-scientific book by researcher

Tags: synonyms, terminology, science, books

I am looking for a synonym for a kind of book/genre, that contains interesting information, but is not aimed at the scientific community, being polemical / political and not stringent enough to be academic. For instance "Weapons of Math Destruction" by Cathy O'Neil.

Comment: So a nonfiction book that isn't a textbook or science book because it doesn't meet the rigors of research or application of the scientific method required for it to be. Well, I'd call that a special-interest book, a book that falls in the literary genre of "special-interest."

Comment: It’s *popular* science.